# C++ How to Reference Other Classes?

Tags: c++, class, object, reference

I'm new to C++, and I'm having some trouble setting up a simple class reference.

Class: Test.hh

```
#ifndef _TEST_HH_
#define _TEST_HH_

class Test {
    public:
        Test (double x);
};

#endif
```

Class Test.cc

```
#include "Test.hh"
#include <stdio.h>

Test::Test(double x) {
   printf("%f",x);
}
```

Now I want to access this class from another class:

Class: DriverClass.hh

```
#ifndef _DRIVERCLASS_HH_
#define _DRIVERCLASS_HH_

#include "Test.hh"

class DriverClass {
    public:
        DriverClass(double y);
        Test *t;
}

#endif
```

Class DriverClass.cc

```
#include "DriverClass.hh"

DriverClass::DriverClass(double y) {
    t = new Test(y);
}
```

However, I get an error: "undefined reference to 'Test::Test(double)?

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Please assume that DriverClass is being called directly from a main method (not shown).

Comment: because you're not linking both compiled objects

Comment: Can you show us how you called the compiler (full command line)?

Comment: `#include "DriverClasss.hh"` - triple `s`? Also `#ifndef`s are not closed.

Comment: Sorry the third "s" and the #endif were just errors when I was copying my code over to stackoverflow. The problem's still the same

Comment: @UKMonkey can you explain? Not sure I follow

Comment: @comp_sci5050 either compile all of your cpp files at once (`g++ *.cpp`) or compile them separately to object files and then link them together(pretty sure you can find out how if you use the search function)

Comment: @comp_sci from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work

At the the linking stage, you're failing to get all your object files included; meaning that your linker knows that the class should exist, and that it should have functions (from the fact that you used it) - but doesn't have the information about the implementation of the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still an error in your post - a missing `;` after the `DriverClass`
declaration. The rest is correct.

You should compile and link all the sources. The following is a sample `Makefile` and a
sample test code.

### Makefile

```
all: t

t: t.cc DriverClass.cc Test.cc
    g++ -Wall -g -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o t
```

However, note that it's generally recommended to compile the sources into objects separately in order to compile only the sources changed after the last compilation. For example:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: t

t: t.o DriverClass.o Test.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

t.o: t.cc DriverClass.o Test.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

DriverClass.o: DriverClass.cc
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

Test.o: Test.cc
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o t
```

I've used the GNU compiler. For the meaning of `$@` and `$^` variables refer to the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

### t.cc

```
#include "Test.hh"
#include "DriverClass.hh"

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  DriverClass d(10.4);
  return 0;
}
```

### Testing

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -g -o t t.cc DriverClass.cc Test.cc
$ ./t
10.400000
```

*P.S.:* don't forget to `delete` the allocated object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had forgotten to add the new classes to my Makefile